# Interpretting Data from a Serialized Network Packet

Tags: sockets, networking, serialization, protobuf-net, packet-capture

I have followed the tutorials on (https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com) to setup my program for packet capturing and I am told that the packet is serialized by protobuf. Currently convertiing the packet to a string (like shown at the bottom) only works for a very little bit of information and will not suffice.

I can't figure out how to get the packet into an acceptable format from below to be able to deserialize it into a format I can use. Below is an example of the packet as it appears in Wireshark.

```
DRDNi|L.TE@4jcP""P.-h"
```

2 
    "
:
"
2 
    "
    "
:
"
2 
    "
    "
"
"
"
"

"
    "
:
"
2 
    "$
    "%
    "4
"
"
    "
    "#
    "
    "
    "
"4+
    "
:
"
2 
    "
:
"
2 
A?CCS2_121-/01
    "C
    "

:
"

2 
    "
:
    "

I am expecting the packets to be in a format similar to this (from what I've been told).

```
list: <
show_entity: <
entity: 29
name: "EX1_306"
tags: <
  name: 45
  value: 3
>
tags: <
  name: 47
  value: 4
>
tags: <
  name: 48
  value: 2
>
tags: <
  name: 49
  value: 1
>
tags: <
  name: 201
  value: 3
>
tags: <
  name: 202
  value: 4
>
tags: <
  name: 203
  value: 2
>
tags: <
  name: 218
  value: 1
>
>
```

The code below is what I am using to capture the packet and convert it to the format where I can read a bit of the information. I can't get the protobuf to deserialize it into any format.

```
    Private Sub PacketCap()
    Dim Index As Integer = 0
    Dim allDevices As IList(Of LivePacketDevice) = LivePacketDevice.AllLocalMachine
    Dim device As LivePacketDevice = allDevices(1)
    Dim Selecteddevice As PacketDevice = device

    Using communicator As PacketCommunicator = Selecteddevice.Open(65536, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000)
        communicator.SetFilter("port 3724")
        ' read timeout

        ' start the capture
        packetcount = 0
        Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                     MetroListbox1.Items.Add("Started Cap")
                                 End Sub))

        communicator.ReceivePackets(0, AddressOf PacketHandler)
    End Using


End Sub

Private Sub MetroButton2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MetroButton2.Click
    Dim N As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf PacketCap)
    N.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub PacketHandler(ByVal packet As PcapDotNet.Packets.Packet)
    Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                 'ListBox1.Items.Add(packet.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff") & " length:" & Convert.ToString(packet.Length) + packet.ToString("X2"))
                                 If packet.Length < 200 Then
                                 Else
                                     Const LineLength As Integer = 64
                                     Dim Info As String
                                     Dim i As Integer = 0
                                     While i <> packet.Length
                                         Info = Info + (packet(i)).ToString("X2")
                                         If (i + 1) Mod LineLength = 0 Then

                                         End If
                                         i += 1
                                     End While
                                 End If

                             End Sub))
```

Sorry about the 'almost complete' formatting, this is my first question here. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Btw - I answered in the general case where you want to be able to handle any data. If you only want to handle the one schema, that is a different much easier scenario - that can probably be spoofed in a handful of lines

Answer (score 0):

The wire specification is [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding). However, the protobuf format is formally ambiguous in the absence of a schema (usually via a .proto file). There is no one single way of interpreting the data. However, you can probably make some wild guesses based on the wire-type (take the first 3 bits of the header).

- 0 is a varint; probably best to simply decode the varint and display it as though it is an int64
- 1 is 64-bit... tricky - no real way to choose between these; perhaps assume fixed64?
- 2 is length-prefixed - you could try the nested content to see if it is UTF-8; if it is, assume it is a string; otherwise, see if it parses as a sub-object; however, it could also be a packed array which is tricky
- 3 is start group - nested sub-object
- 4 is end group - end of the above
- 5 is 32-bit - like 1 - perhaps assume fixed32?

Frankly, though, this is going to be **so** hit and miss (mostly miss) that I don't see much point.